# Writing $f(x)$ in terms of the heaviside function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, special-functions

I have $f(x,t) = 0$ when $t \le 0$ and $f(x,t) = \sin(-x + t)$ when $t > 0$.

I have been told this can be written more concisely in terms of the heavisdie function $u(t - a)$ as

$f(x,t) = \sin(-x + t)u(-x +t)$

I don't see how this is equivalent to the original statement for $f$? Whenever I have used the heaviside function before it has been with 1 dimensions, $t$, not $t$ and $x$ as we have here, so it is strange seeing it being used with a variable $x$ rather than a constant $a$.

Can someone explain to me how the two versions of $f(x,t)$ above are the same?

** ***EDIT*** **

My question was a simplified version of the actual equation I was dealing with. Here is the actual equation and it's representation using the heaviside function. So can someone explain how these two $W(x,t)'s$ are the same?
[image]

Comment: edit $f(x)$ to $f(x,t)$. Stackexchange does not allow me to edit only for two bytes.

Comment: @sonicboom : FYI, when I learnt heaviside function, i was told that $u(t-a)=0$ if $t<a$ and  $u(t-a)=1$ if $t>a$. Some textbooks use the notation $u_a(t)$ instead of $u(t-a)$. I suggest you recap the definition of the heaviside function and i think the above $f(x,t)$ is not correct

Answer (score 2):

Something is wrong. 
$$\sin(-x+t)u(-x+t)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $t\le x$}\\\sin(-x+t)&\text{if $t>x$}\end{cases} $$
For your given function, you'd need someting like $f(x,t)=\sin(-x+t)u(t)$ and be careful what happens at $t=0$ (there are different specifications of $u$ in the wild, sometimes $u(0)=\frac12$, sometimes $u(0)=1$, ...)

Comment: Hi, I have edited my post to show the original non-simplified equations.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=6\pi$ and $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the two formulas don't agree.

you might want $$ \sin(-x+t)u(t)$$